# django run custom views class method with one url

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-models, django-templates

I'm new to django. I want to manage my database with custom methods inside the views file. for example, I have this code I would like to run with javascript - I wrote this code:

**Js:**

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ClassManager/',
        data: {
            data: data,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("IT WORKED")
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
```

**views.py**

```py
def expfunc():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
            addlst = List(content = "list content", creator = user)
            addlst.save()
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('ClassManager/', views.expfunc),
]
```

now, the problem is, that for every new function that I want to create in the views.py, I need to add another line in the urls.py.

my question is - if there a way to create a class with all of the custom methods, and access them with one url and different data?

for example:

**Js:**

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ClassManager/functionone()',
        data: {
            data: data
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("IT WORKED")
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
```

**views.py**

```py
class DatabaseManager():
    def functionone(): # add new list
        if request.method == 'POST':
                user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
                addlst = List(content = "list content", creator = user)
                addlst.save()
    def functwo(): # update username
        if request.method == 'POST':
                user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
                user.id = 9
                user.save()
    def functhree(): # update list content
        if request.method == 'POST':
                user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
                mylist = List.objects.get(pk=1)
                mylist.content = "updated list content"
                mylist.save()
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('ClassManager/functionone()', views.DatabaseManager.functionone),
]
```

I came from asp.net background where I wrote classes with functions that ran queries and that it how I managed my database, so can I do the same here?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Class Based View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/) to implement your views as Python objects instead of functions, but you can't call a class function with Ajax.

Comment: class based views only have 8 specific methods that I can use... I cant create custom ones, and I still will need to add new line in urls.py for every method. Is this how you code in django? for every views method I need to add new line in urls.py? as I said: I'm new to django. tysm

Comment: Yes! You need to add an url for each view

Comment: alright, thanks! one last question if i may: do you know any other way to get the same result with only one url and multiple custom functions?